# Inverting a Coordinate Transformation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given $x(s,t)=s+t$ and $y(s,t)=st$ is it possible to find $s$ and $t$ as functions of $x$ and $y$?

I'm given a function $f(x,y)=x^2+xy+y^2$ and told it is expressed as $h(s,t)$ where $x(s,t)=s+t$ and $y(s,t)=st$. It asks to find the partial derivative of $h$ with respect to $t$ *in Cartesian coordinates*, but when I apply the chain rule I end up with:

$h_t=2x+2y+(2y+x)s$ and I can't figure out how to invert the transformation to covert the $s$ into $x$'s and $y$'s. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Think about this: you need to wind up with $s(x,y)$ and $t(x,y)$, but for example, $s(x,y)$ can't depend on $t$. So how would you go about removing $t$ from the system of equations you have? Take a good hard look at

$$\begin{align}
x &= s + t &
y &= st
\end{align}$$

and think about what you could do that would leave you without a $t$.